# How to increase width of bar chart using achart engine in android?

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using achartengine for showing a single bar chart in my app for a view. I need to increase the width of the bar. This is my code

```
    CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Demo Bar Graph");
    series.add(65);



    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    mRenderer.setXAxisMin(2);
    mRenderer.setXAxisMax(2);       
    mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    mRenderer.setYAxisMax(50);
```

Answer (score 0):

try Using Below Code

**`renderer.setBarSpacing(-0.5);`**

Comment: I need to show the bar chart in a view with a width of 100dp, but the bar chart is still very narrow even though I gave bar spacing(I want to show only a single bar chart)